# WPF c# datagrid set individual row height

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am pretty new to WPF and C#.
I am trying to create a datagrid where I can programmatically set the height of the individual rows.

It seems possible to change the height for all the rows together, but I would like the rows to have different heights from each other.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?
(I was thinking I could set the row height to automatic, and put an invisible TextBox in an unused column.  I could change the height of the unused TextBox programmatically.)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing is probably to handle this in the [DataGrid.LoadingRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.loadingrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event which is raised right after a row is instatiated.

To do so just add an event handler to your datagrid in the xaml code:

```
<DataGrid LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow"></DataGrid>
```

And declare this eventhandler in your code to manage the row height individually via the `Height` property:

```
private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = e.Row;
    row.Height = 50; //put your height here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EKrueger,

Thank you very much for your response.

Your technique however, only happens when the datagrid is created.
I need something that I can call at different times so I can resize my rows on a regular basis.

I kept searching and here is the solution I found.

Cheers.

- Matt

  ```
  private void resizeDataGridRowHeight() {
      int a = boundDataGrid.Items.Count;
      int calibrationRowHeight = 28;
      for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
          myRowHeight = ListofObjectsThatEachRepresentAParameter.ListOfDataTableRows[i].ListOfCalibrationRows.Count * calibrationRowHeight;
          DataGridRow row = boundDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
          row = boundDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
          row.Height = myRowHeight;
      }
  }
  ```